# Человек нажимает купить, оплачивает и ему отправляется файл

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, на сайте человек нажимает купить, оплачивает, как сделать чтоб после этого на mail ему автоматически приходило письмо с определенным текстом

Comment: Формулировка вопроса замечательная.
Это случайно не учебное задание?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? Вы ведь не хотите, чтобы мы за вас всё написали, вы активно работаете над проблемой, и столкнулись с какой-то конкретной трудностью, ведь так?

Answer (score 3):

судя по вашим меткам - никак. Какой серверный язык используете? Если `php`, то функция `mail`.

Comment: +1 за первое предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Вы знаете как принять и обработать платеж в интернете, но не знаете как письмо отправить? Забавно. 
Как уже было сказано выше, в случае с php используйте [mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)
Выбраные вами метки(html и javascript) вообще не в тему